# EF Core: AutoMapper ProjectTo ToListAsync throws "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, automapper

I'm querying some entities from ef core context and then initialize a dto:

```
IQueryable<EntityType> entities = _context
                        .Entities
                        .Where(q => true)
                        .GroupBy(q => q.SomeProperty)
                        .Select(g => new GroupedEntity { Key = g.Key, Entities = g });

                    var dto = new Dto(Whatever = "whatever");
```

The following works fine:

```
dto.List = entities
                 .ProjectTo<Dto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                 .ToList();
```

But if I try to make this call async, it fails.

```
dto.List = await entities
                     .ProjectTo<Dto>(_mapper.ConfigurationProvider)
                     .ToListAsync();
```

Exception:

Message: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.
Source: Anonymously Hosted DynamicMethods Assembly
Stack Trace:

> at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.TaskLiftingExpressionVisitor.<_ExecuteAsync>d__8 1.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.AsyncSelectEnumerable 2.AsyncSelectEnumerator.d__3.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable 1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.d__6 3.MoveNext() in
>   D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Aggregate.cs:line 128 
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.ExpressionVisitors.Internal.TaskLiftingExpressionVisitor.<_ExecuteAsync>d__8 1.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.AsyncSelectEnumerable 2.AsyncSelectEnumerator.d__3.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult() 
>   at
>   Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Query.Internal.AsyncLinqOperatorProvider.ExceptionInterceptor 1.EnumeratorExceptionInterceptor.d__5.MoveNext()
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.ConfiguredTaskAwaitable 1.ConfiguredTaskAwaiter.GetResult()
>   at System.Linq.AsyncEnumerable.d__6 3.MoveNext() in
>   D:\a\1\s\Ix.NET\Source\System.Interactive.Async\Aggregate.cs:line 128 
>   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw()
>   at
>   System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task
>   task)    at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter 1.GetResult()

Versions:

- target framework: netcoreapp2.2
- Entity Framework Core 2.2.6
- AutoMapper 8.1.1

Comment: Upgrade EF Core.

Comment: @LucianBargaoanu Thanks for your comment. Is it a known ef core bug or why would an upgrade help? It's the project of a customer so I cannot upgrade packages as easily

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised. Worst case scenario, you find out where to look further.